# Retrieve data from excel column and write values in a temp file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Right now, I am able to retrieve the necessary data. However, I end up creating multiple temp files. I think my issue is that my function closes the files and then my do until starts the process over again. I am new and not sure how to make it seamless to write to one temp file and then close once done. Any input or ideas would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'Set the excel logic. 
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim strFilename As String 
        xlApp = New Excel.Application

        'Select .xlsm file with file dialog box and set to TraceSelection.Text
        If IO.File.Exists(TraceSelection.Text) Then xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TraceSelection.Text)
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook

        'Populate Temp File.
        Dim trace As Object
        trace = xlWorkBook.Sheets("2020-12-16_12-07-12_781")

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim testing As String
        'Dim pgn_hex_value As String
        i = 2 'Starting from two since the first row is the header
        Do Until trace.Range("E" & i) Is ""
            testing = trace.Range("E" & i).Value
            strFilename = WriteToTempFile(testing)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        MessageBox.Show(strFilename)
    End Sub
```

The function I have created below creates the temp file

```
Public Function WriteToTempFile(ByVal Data As String) As String
        ' Writes text to a temporary file and returns path
        Dim strFilename As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
        Dim objFS As New System.IO.FileStream(strFilename, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        ' Opens stream and begins writing
        Dim Writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(objFS)
        Writer.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.End)
        Writer.WriteLine(Data)
        Writer.Flush()
        ' Closes and returns temp path
        Writer.Close()
        Return strFilename
    End Function
```

Comment: Move the file creation bit (`...GetTempFileName()`) out of the method and call it just before the loop.  Add a file param to WriteToTempFile to take that file and just write to it.

Comment: u want to write data in one file or multiple file ? if yes, pass file name also to write in different files like Public Function WriteToTempFile(ByVal Data As String,ByVal filename As String) As String
Dim strFilename As String = filename or u give system current datetime in the file name.

Comment: I will try the above...to provide more context. I am trying to write cells A2 through AX in one Temp file one line after another. Currently, this returns A2 and creates temp. Then returns A3 and puts it in a separate temp, I would like them to be in the same temp.